# Explicitly subclass a protocol and still not implement it

Tags: python, python-typing

In [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#terminology), it's mentioned that

> (Note that one can explicitly subclass a protocol and still not implement it if a protocol attribute is set to None in the subclass, see Python [[data-model](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#data-model)] for details.)

However, I didn't quite understand that. What does that mean? Which protocol attribute should be set to `None`?

Comment: What do you mean _"Which protocol attribute"_? If _any_ of the attributes required by the protocol is overridden with `None`, your subclass wouldn't still implement it. In the likely event that you don't _want_ to break the Liskov substitution principle, the fact that you _could_ isn't relevant to you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, why should I set an attribute to `None` rather than not define it. In both cases, type checker will raise an error on that. I understood the mentioned clause as that it's "legal" to set something to `None` in order to subclass a Protocol without implementing it. Moreover, I didn't which part in [data-model] is related.

Comment: There's no "should". You probably _shouldn't_ inherit-but-not-implement a protocol. As to why set it to `None`: if you don't define it at all, you inherit the implementation from the superclass.

Comment: "why should I set an attribute to None rather than not define it" - this quote doesn't say anything about what you *should* do. The quote is about the implications of things you *can* do.

Comment: "As to why set it to None: if you don't define it at all, you inherit the implementation from the superclass." - and while that implementation will probably just be `...` or `pass` in this case, that's still technically an implementation.

Comment: @user2357112, Then why `None` is special here? I can even define any attribute to `...`, breaking the protocol.

Comment: Out of curiosity I implemented this: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=e383cf41945f54fd7a41ee0bbd5caab8 It seems like in the case described mypy is happy to accept the "subclass non-implementation" wherever is annotated for the protocol (presumably because it's still a subclass) but will error at the definition site.

Comment: @FangHung-chien: `None` is the standard "I'm explicitly de-implementing this" marker, special-cased in the `__instancecheck__` for protocol classes, and in a few other places in the language core.

Comment: ...and in the case of defining a dummy method with `...` for body, mypy will accept it if the protocol has it returning `None` but else will complain `Missing return statement  [empty-body]` for other return types, but otherwise behaves the same (subclass-ness trumps protocol non-implementation)

Comment: "see Python [data-model] for details"... for details of "None"? If you look at the reference, it's liked to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names. I think it was related to some magic names.

Comment: Maybe I got confused because I've thought too much more than the author wanted to express.

Answer (score 0):

As written, it is easy to not understand what this sentence actually means. For a clearer description, imagine it reads:

> Note that one can explicitly subclass a protocol and still not implement it if any or all of that protocol's attributes are set to None in the subclass

(and as mentioned in comments, by explicitly setting a protocol attribute to `None` you prevent your class from inheriting the protocol's variables and methods: setting *any* attribute to `None` in order to "break the contract" will prevent the protocol's variables and methods from being inherited, while the protocol itself can still be found in the MRO chain)

Comment: This sentence is quite confusing here. "one can explicitly subclass a protocol and still not implement it if any or all of that protocol's attributes are set to ANYTHING other than the protocol specifies". I don't understand why "set to None" is particularly mentioned here.

Comment: Because that's the Pythonic way to mark something as "I am explicitly saying that this is not a thing here". It's how Python scripts are supposed to mark something as "being nothing". You need _some_ kind of code to say that and using `None` is how Python says you do that: if you want to "unset" something, you explicitly mark it as `None`.

Comment: Then what's the difference between defining a protocol attribute to `None` and not to define it, or even to define it to be `False`/`"hello"`/`lambda x: 42`, for example. In all cases that subclass does not correctly implement the protocol it subclasses to. And in all cases type checker raises errors on that attribute. I understood that set to `None` nothing special but one case of not implementing all required protocol attributes. So, I thought the author of the PEP wanted to say something different, by setting some magic var to `None` so to make that legal -- I mean no type error.

Comment: I think it was I thought too much.

Comment: "Not defining it" means you have no code, which means your subclass inherits the protocol, the end. That's what is supposed to happen. However, _if_ you want to mess with the MRO and you _don't_ want to inherit the protocol, you can mark any or all protocol-defined attributes as `None`. Now Python sees that your subclass _cannot_ inherit the protocol because unlike regular class inheritance, protocols are all or nothing: _either_ your subclass matches the protocol in full, or it doesn't and it gets nothing. There's no partial implementation.

Comment: As for "why not anything else that's "something" but that isn't `None`?", because Python is an opinionated language, and the convention is that if you need a binding, and that binding needs to represent "nothing", you use `None`. The end. You don't bind `False`, because that means it's a value, and that value is False. Same for `"hello"` or a lambda: you don't _want_ it to be something, you are telling Python that you want it to be _nothing_, and in Python, that's `None`. =)

Comment: (As for "okay but _will_ it work?", that's where we refer back to PEP544: the spec only says what happens when `None` is used. If you use something else, the behaviour of your code is _not defined_, so maybe it works, maybe it won't, and maybe half a second later it won't do what it did a second ago. Asking whether other value work has no value; the spec only defines behaviour given `None`)